# How to set Context in AlertDialog.Builder() when called in an Adapter in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-alertdialog, android-context

I am new to Kotlin. I am trying to use an AlertDialog box when a button which is part of a RecyclerView is pressed. The RecylerView adapter is called in the MainActivity.

Below is my code in the adapter. Using 'this'for the context for AlertDialog.Builder(this) brings an error, as I need to provide a context, but 'this' is recognized as an adapter. I have tried many things to solve it without success.

How can i set the context properly?

```
class contactAdapter (val contacts: ArrayList<Contact>, val contactClick: (Contact) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.Adapter<contactAdapter.Viewholder>() {.......

fun reminderButtonClicked (view:View){
        reminderAlertDialog() // call the dialogbox when this button is pressed in the recyclerview
    }

    fun reminderAlertDialog(){
        val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        val dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.reminder_alert_dialog,null)

        dialog.setView(dialogView)
        dialog.setCancelable(true)
        val myAlertDialog = dialog.show()
....
}
```

Comment: Add context as argument to your adapter

Comment: @Yoleth that works for most of the times but still throw some errors in-case the base activity gets destroyed.

Comment: Why don't you render dialog from activity instead of adapter ? Use Unit to get click action from adapter into activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Views have a reference to `Context`, so the following should work:

```
fun reminderButtonClicked(view: View) {
  reminderAlertDialog(view.context)
}

fun reminderAlertDialog(context: Context) {
  val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
  ...
}
```